# using sed find a word and append a suffix at the end of the matched word

Tags: linux, sed

I have some texts in the file looking like:

```
'PALAL_3002_NEP_POLICIES':
 Name: SomeRandomName:Here
 Desc: "Random description here"
 Chart Name: palal
 Labels:
 - Label1: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY'
 - Label2: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_SER_PSA_NEP_POLICY-DUMMY_SER_PAL_NEP'
 - Label3: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY-DUMMY_SER_NEG_NEP'
 - Label4: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY-#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY'
```

I want to find a word containing a string `PAL` in capital letters and suffix the matched word with `_MATCH`. The string `PAL` can exist in a word without hyphen , or with hyphen separated.

Expected output:

```
'PALAL_3002_NEP_POLICIES_MATCH': 
 Name: SomeRandomName:Here
 Desc: "Random description here"
 Chart Name: palal
 Labels:
 - Label1: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY_MATCH'
 - Label2: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_SER_PSA_NEP_POLICY-DUMMY_SER_PAL_NEP_MATCH'
 - Label3: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY_MATCH-DUMMY_SER_NEG_NEP'
 - Label4: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY_MATCH-#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY_MATCH'
```

This is what I did but it suffixed every words with `_MATCH`:

`sed '/PAL/s/\>/_MATCH/g' practice.txt`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text you want to append to only contains uppercase characters, digits and underscores, you can use the following:

```
sed 's/\(PAL[A-Z_0-9]*\)/\1_MATCH/g' foo
       \(             \)                    #capturing group
         PAL                                #literal text
            [A-Z_0-9]                       #character class, any of the contained characters
                     *                      #quantifier, match previous expression between 1 to infinity times
                         \1                 #backreference to the first capturing group
                           _MATCH           #literal text, suffix
```

#### Example:

```
╰─$ sed 's/\(PAL[A-Z_0-9]*\)/\1_MATCH/g' foo

'PALAL_3002_NEP_POLICIES_MATCH':
 Name: SomeRandomName:Here
 Desc: "Random description here"
 Chart Name: palal
 Labels:
 - Label: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY_MATCH'
```

Comment: I forget to add one condition, and this condition uses Hyphen to separate words. I have edited the question, can you please give it another look? apologies for the hassle.

Comment: @ishworkafley the command still produces the exact result specified in your recent edit. Note that **any character** other than [A-Z0-9_] will be treated as "seperator"

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "/PAL/s/\(.*\)\('\)/\1_MATCH\2/" input_file
'PALAL_3002_NEP_POLICIES_MATCH':
 Name: SomeRandomName:Here
 Desc: "Random description here"
 Chart Name: palal
 Labels:
 - Label: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY_MATCH'
```

Comment: the solution you suggested worked perfectly. But I forget to add one condition, and this condition uses Hyphen to separate words. I have edited the question, can you please give it another look? apologies for the hassle.

Comment: @ishworkafley I have run the code against your new sample. It still seems to work. What is not working for you?

Comment: - Label4: '#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY-#AL_RAND_DUMMY_PAL_PSA_NEP_POLICY'   not working for this condition. The another solution suggested by @mashuptwice seemed to work. thank you for your time :)